# Scope of with torch.no_grad() in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autograd

```
with torch.no_grad():
    input = Variable(input).cuda()
    target = Variable(target).cuda(non_blocking=True)
y=model(input)
# many things here
```

Is the no_grad continue to having effect out of the "with" scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `no_grad` has no effect outside the "with" scope.

According to this [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/two-small-questions-about-with-torch-no-grad/27571/2) from a moderator on the pytorch blog:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    # No gradients in this block
    x = self.cnn(x)

# Gradients as usual outside of it
x = self.lstm(x)
```

It is the purpose of the `with` statement in python. The variable used  by the `with` (here `torch.no_grad()`) has only effect in the `with` context and not after. See the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) for complete details.